# Multiplying a list by many random variates and saving each result in a table

Tags: list-manipulation

This is probably an exceedingly simple question, I apologize in advance.

Basically, I have a list of values I create:

```
nrpara = 0.5; 
n = 100000;
xmin = 100000; 
alpha = 1.3; 
data = 
  Transpose[
    Table[
      {n^(1/alpha xmin 1/(i^(1/alpha)), 1 - ((n + 1 - i)/((1/(1 - nrpara)) n))}, 
      {i, 1, n}]]; 
list = Table[{data[[1, i]], 1}, {i, 1, 50}];
```

Now, what I want to do is multiply this list 20 times with a random variate I generate like so:

```
randomvariate = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 2], 20]
```

In the end I want to be able to evaluate `mixedlist[[i]]` and get a multiplication of `list` with the i-th of the 20 random-variates.

Comment: What is `mixedlist`? And what is the second `1` for, in the definition of `list`?

Comment: `mixedlist = list*# & /@ randomvariate` ?

Comment: please verify the dimensions of your data: `list` is expected to be `{50,2}`, `randomvariate` is expected to be `{20,1}`; is this information correct? also, what are the expected dimensions of `mixedlist`?

Answer (score 1):

```
mixedlist = Outer[Times, randomvariate, list, 1]
```

Or, if you don't mean to scale the index:

```
mixedlist = Outer[{#1*First@#2, Last@#2} &, randomvariate, list, 1]
```